# Change Connection String via code

Tags: vba, excel, connection-string

I have 9 sheets that connect to different tables in teradata, each time i have to enter my user name and password to refresh and get new set of data. could someone please advice how do i write a VBA code that could change the connection string for each connection and refresh the data table.I am a begginner in VBA and have no clue in codding in VBA

Thanks
Syam

Comment: How is the data being retrieved? Via VBA Macros or by some other method?

Comment: try recording a macro while refreshing the data and then using this macro (attached to the click on a button somewhere in your sheet) or a modified version of it, to update the connections when the data needs refreshing in the future.  this approach works when you want to learn how to automate almost anything in excel/vba (as you can dissect the recorded macro to see how Microsoft would perform the task in code).

Comment: Hi Shiva, I am getting the data through ODBC COnnection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I do: I put the following in cells A2:B5
Data Source: 
Database:

I put the SQL in cell D2. I use Row 1 for telling me how long the query takes. Then, I add a button anywhere on the page. Then I call the code below. It looks complicated, but the core of the functionality is all in Get_Data_Teradata.

The Get_SQL Function simply reads down column D until it finds a blank row and then returns a big block of text for the SQL. You could replace this with a hardcoded SQL statement.

Pop_Col_Heads puts the column headings from the result in Row 1. Note, that I have discovered a Bug in Excel 2010 on Win 7 where I can only populate columns once or twice per Excel session. If I quit and load Excel again, it works another once or twice.

Copy_Data_From_RDBMS places the ADODB RecordSet into a range in the active sheet. I had to do some tweaks to handle inserts and updates because they don't return any rows.

```
Sub Get_Data_Teradata()
'Supports Multi Query
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sConnect As String
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmdSQLData As ADODB.Command
    Set cmdSQLData = New ADODB.Command
    Dim sQueries() As String

    sConnect = "Persist Security Info=True; Session Mode=ANSI; " & _
               "Data Source=" & ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value & ";" & _
               "Database=" & ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value & ";" & _
               "User ID=" & ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value & ";" & _
               "Password=" & ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & ";"
    sQueries = Get_SQL(ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D9999"))
    nRow = 1 'initialize to start at the top of the page
    For i = 0 To UBound(sQueries) - 1
        cn.Open sConnect
        Set cmdSQLData.ActiveConnection = cn
        cmdSQLData.CommandText = sQueries(i) 'TELL VBA TO LOAD THE QUERY INTO TERADATA
        cmdSQLData.CommandType = adCmdText
        cmdSQLData.CommandTimeout = 0
        Set rs = cmdSQLData.Execute()
        Call Pop_Col_Heads(rs, nRow)
        nRow = Copy_Data_From_RDBMS(rs, nRow)
        cn.Close
    Next i
End Sub

Dim a As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim nIndex As Long
Dim sSQL() As String


Function Get_SQL(oRange As Object) As String()
'First figure out how many rows the SQL statement is
a = 0
    For Each cCell In oRange
        a = a + 1
        If cCell.Value = "" Then
            a = a - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cCell

'Num rows = a now
'Step through and parse into array
    i = 0
    nIndex = 0
    ReDim Preserve sSQL(1)
    For Each cCell In oRange
        i = i + 1
        If i > a Then
            Exit For
        ElseIf cCell.Value = "<Multi>" Then
            nIndex = nIndex + 1
            ReDim Preserve sSQL(nIndex + 1)
        Else
            sSQL(nIndex) = sSQL(nIndex) & To_Text(cCell.Value) & " "
        End If
    Next cCell
    Get_SQL = sSQL
End Function

Sub Pop_Col_Heads(rs As Object, nRow As Long)
    Dim rHeads As Range
    Dim fFields As Field
    Dim nCol As Integer

    nCol = 0
    If nRow = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("E1:ZZ1").ClearContents
    End If
    Set rHeads = ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Offset(nRow - 1, 0)
    Do While nCol < rs.Fields.Count
        sTemp = rs.Fields(nCol).Name
        rHeads.Cells(nRow, nCol + 1).Value = rs.Fields(nCol).Name
        ActiveSheet.Calculate
        rHeads.Cells(nRow, nCol + 1).Value = sTemp
        nCol = nCol + 1
        rHeads.WrapText = True
        rHeads.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignTop
    Loop
End Sub

Function Copy_Data_From_RDBMS(rs As Object, nRow As Long) As Long
'Supports Multi Query
    If nRow = 1 Then
        x = Get_Last_Row_Find(ActiveSheet.Range("E1:ZZ64000"))
        ActiveSheet.Range("E2:ZZ" & x).ClearContents
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    rs.MoveFirst
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Offset(nRow - 1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
        x = Get_Last_Row_Find(ActiveSheet.Range("E1:ZZ64000"))
        Copy_Data_From_RDBMS = x + 1
        ActiveSheet.Range("E2:ZZ" & x).Offset(nRow - 1, 0).WrapText = False
    Else 'no results (e.g. insert)
        ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Offset(nRow - 1, 0).Value = "<no data returned>"
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```